# Assign a coordinate in polar method, with an origin different than (0,0)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the followint MWE. I am trying to calculate the coordinate of the upper point end of the blue line, determined initially by +(45:2), and assign this coordinate to point B. Don't know how to do that...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,calc,chains,intersections,through,backgrounds,patterns,positioning,quotes,decorations}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (ORG) at (0.00, 0.00);
        \fill[red] (ORG) circle (2pt) node[above left] {O};

    \coordinate (A) at (1.00, 2.00);
    \fill[red] (A) circle (2pt) node[above left] {A};
    \draw[blue, line width=1.50pt] (A) -- +(45:2);

    \coordinate (B) at (45:4); %+(45:2)
    \fill[magenta] (B) circle (3pt);
    \fill[magenta] (B) circle (3pt) node[above right] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,calc,chains,intersections,through,backgrounds,patterns,positioning,quotes,decorations}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (ORG) at (0.00, 0.00);
        \fill[red] (ORG) circle (2pt) node[above left] {O};

    \coordinate (A) at (1.00, 2.00);
    \fill[red] (A) circle (2pt) node[above left] {A};
    \draw[blue, line width=1.50pt] (A) -- +(45:2)coordinate(B);

    \fill[magenta] (B) circle (3pt);
    \fill[magenta] (B) circle (3pt) node[above right] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign the coordinate B "directly" without actually drawing anything? Like using the path instruction, or the coordinate instruction directly?